# Delete rows after a certain sequence of values in a certain column

Tags: r, rows

```
a <- c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","D","D","D","D","D")
b <- c("x","y","z","x","x","z","y","z","z","z","y","z","z","z","x")
df = data.frame(a,b)


    a   b
1   A   x
2   A   y
3   A   z
4   B   x
5   B   x
6   B   z
7   C   y
8   C   z
9   C   z
10  C   z
11  D   y
12  D   z
13  D   z
14  D   z
15  D   x
```

For every group A, B, C, D, I'd like to delete the value z in column b every time the combination y,z appears at the end of the group.

If we have the case of a=="C", where the b-values are y,z,z,z, I'd like to delete all z's. However, in a=="D", nothing has to change as x is the last value.

The results looks like this:

```
    a   b
1   A   x
2   A   y
4   B   x
5   B   x
6   B   z
7   C   y
11  D   y
12  D   z
13  D   z
14  D   z
15  D   x
```

By grouping in `dplyr`, I can identify the last occurence of each value in A, so the basic case depictured in `a=="A"`is not a problem. I have trouble finding a solution for the case of `a=="C"`, where I could have one occurence of y followed by 20 occurences of z.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `by` and `cummin` in base R:

```
df[unlist(by(df$b, interaction(df$a), FUN = function(x) {
  tmp <- rev(cummin(rev(x == "z")))
  if (tail(x[!tmp], 1) == "y") !tmp else rep(TRUE, length(x))
})), ]
```

The result:

```
   a b
1  A x
2  A y
4  B x
5  B x
6  B z
7  C y
11 D y
12 D z
13 D z
14 D z
15 D x
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a possible `data.table` solution. Basically, I'm creating an logical index that satisfies 3 conditions at once: being a `z`, that the first `z` comes after `y` and that the last value is `z` and then I'm just evaluating it.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, indx := b == "z" & 
            max(which(b == "z")) == .N &
            ifelse(min(which(b == "z")) == 1L, 
                   TRUE, 
                   b[min(which(b == "z")) - 1L] == "y"),
            by = a][!(indx)]
#     a b  indx
#  1: A x FALSE
#  2: A y FALSE
#  3: B x FALSE
#  4: B x FALSE
#  5: B z FALSE
#  6: C y FALSE
#  7: D y FALSE
#  8: D z FALSE
#  9: D z FALSE
# 10: D z FALSE
# 11: D x FALSE
```

Comment: my question was not completely clear, but I was too late to answer to your comment. the combination I am looking for is the sequence y z. If you take a <- c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","D","D","D","D","D","E","E","E")
b <- c("x","y","z","x","x","z","y","z","z","z","y","z","z","z","x","z","z","y")
df = data.frame(a,b), nothing should change for `a=="E"`

Comment: See my edit, though with a bit more thought, I can probably come up with something nicer probably...

Comment: The solution does not take into account that z should only be removed if "the combination y,z appears at the end of the group". In case this combination appears earlier (e.g. for A in `a <- c("A","A","A","A","A","A","C","C","C","C","D","D","D","D","D")
b <- c("x","y","z","x","y","z","y","z","z","z","y","z","z","z","x")`, your solution removes the earlier z too.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base solution:

```
do.call("rbind", by(df, df$a, FUN = function(x) {
    if(x$b[length(x$b)] == "z") {
        y <- which(x$b == "y")
        if(!length(y)) {
            return(x)
        }
        z <- which(x$b == "z")
        if(!length(z)) {
            return(x)
        }
        # check if y isn't immediately before z
        if(max(y) - min(z) > 1) {
            return(x)
        } else {
            return(x[-z,])
        }
    } else {
        return(x)
    }
}))
```

And the result:

```
     a b
A.1  A x
A.2  A y
B.4  B x
B.5  B x
B.6  B z
C    C y
D.11 D y
D.12 D z
D.13 D z
D.14 D z
D.15 D x
```

Answer (score 1):

Not so efficient, but works fine:

```
require(stringr)
df2 <- data.frame(row.names = c("a", "b")) 

for(i in levels(factor(df$a))) {
  temp <- paste(df$b[df$a == i], collapse = "")
  if(str_detect(temp, "yz") & str_detect(temp, "z$")) {
    temp <- gsub("z", "", temp)
    df2 <- rbind(df2, data.frame(a = rep(i, nchar(temp)), b = substring(temp, seq(1,nchar(temp),1), seq(1,nchar(temp),1))))
  } else df2 <- rbind(df2, data.frame(a = rep(i, nchar(temp)), b = substring(temp, seq(1,nchar(temp),1), seq(1,nchar(temp),1))))   
}

#    a b
# 1  A x
# 2  A y
# 3  B x
# 4  B x
# 5  B z
# 6  C y
# 7  D y
# 8  D z
# 9  D z
# 10 D z
# 11 D x
```